# Optional grouping with Regex in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have a file with many different file path locations.  Some of them have multiple directory depth and some don't.  What I need to do is prepend a directory `/WEB_ROOT/` to all file path locations in the file.

For example

`index.jsp` -> `/WEB_ROOT/index.jsp`

`/instructor/assigned_appts.jsp` -> `/WEB_ROOT/instructor/assigned_appts.jsp`

I have tried this one `([\/_]?[A-Za-z]*).jsp` to try and capture the optional `_ and /` values but this doesn't match properly.

`/instructor/assigned_appts.jsp` only matches `_appts.jsp`

I have tried this as well `([\/_]?[A-Za-z])*.jsp` which properly matches all expected file paths but when I replace I only get the last letter instead of the full group

So a replace with `/WEB_ROOT/$1.jsp` gives the following

`index.jsp` -> `/WEB_ROOT/x.jsp`

`/instructor/assigned_appts.jsp` -> `/WEB_ROOT/s.jsp`

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the whole line, and as `[\/_]?` is optional, make sure that you match at least a single char A-Za-z before the `.jsp`

If you want to replace with group 1 like `/WEB_ROOT/$1` you can also capture the `.jsp`

```
(.*[A-Za-z]\.jsp)
```

Note sure if supported in eclipse, but you might also just get the whole match and use `$0` instead of group 1

```
.*[A-Za-z]\.jsp
```

If `.jsp` is at the end of the string, you can append an anchor `.*[A-Za-z]\.jsp$`